# Avoiding divide by zero in MapBasic?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

In select statement how to avoid divide by zero in MapBasic:

```
select (col1/col2) "result"
```

If col2 is 0 it returns null.

How to use ISNULL or something in mapbasic?

Comment: Usually, any selection based on a quotient can be replaced by a selection based on a product that is algebraically equivalent to the quotient for nonzero denominators (and creates no divide-by-zero problems).  What specifically is your select statement?

Comment: @whuber I added 0.01 to divider and it solved the issue. In my situation I changed col2  (col2+0.01).I wondered if any options isnull,default or something exist.

Comment: Select (col1/col2) where col2 != 0   ?

Comment: As stated in the comment above, you could add a condition to the query which would filter out those records where col2 = 2, or in other words only will keep those records where col2 <> 0